# How to package C++ application along with its all dependencies for deployment

Tags: c++, docker, gcc, cmake, makefile

I have a C++ application which depends on several other third party projects which I clone and build from source. I wanted to now deploy this application as a docker container. Consider following directory structure

```
workspace
├── dependency-project-1
|   ├── lib
|   ├── build
|   ├── include
|   ├── src
|   └── Thirdparty
|      ├── sub-dependency-project-1
|      |  ├── lib
|      |  ├── build
|      |  ├── include
|      |  ├── src
|      |  └── CMakeLists.txt
|      └── sub-dependency-project-N
├── dependency-project-N (with similar structure as dependency-project-1)
└── main-project (with similar structure as dependency-project-1 and depedent on dependency projects above)
```

Those `build` and `lib` folders are created when I built those projects with `cmake` and `make`. I used to run app from `workspace/main-project/build/MyApp`

For deployment, I felt that I will create two stage dockerfile. In one stage I will build all the projects and in second stage I will only copy `build` folder from first stage. The build was successful. But while running the app from the container, it gave following error:

```
./MyApp: error while loading shared libraries: dependency-project-1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This `.so` file was in `workspace/dependency-project-1/lib` folder which I did not copy in second stage of dockerfile.

Now I am thinking how can gather all build artefacts (`build`, `lib` and all other build output from all dependency projects and their sub-dependency projects) into one location and then copy them to final image in the second stage of the dockerfile.

I tried to run `make DESTDIR=/workspace/install install` inside `workspace/main-project/build` in the hope that it will gather all the dependencies in the `/workspace/install` folder. But it does not seem to have done that. I could not find `MyApp` in this directory.

What is standard solution to this scenarion?

Comment: This is a cmake question so the `makefile` tag is not relevant.  It's also not really a docker question.

Comment: My understanding of the way cmake works is that the install operation installs the targets that were built by the CMakeLists.txt file.  It won't install external or third-party targets, that your project links with but doesn't build.  Normally that is not what you want, because normally the third party targets that cmake locates are assumed to already be installed (after all cmake found them): it would be wrong to install them "again" even if `DESTDIR` is set.